# Quadpod or tetrapod?

Tags: numbers, latin, greek

If you have a 'pod' with two legs, you get a bipod. Three legs and you get a tripod.

Is a four legged pod more correctly called a quadpod, tetrapod or something else?

Comment: 'pod' is the ancient Greek word for foot or leg.  Bipod means "two-leg".

Comment: [tetrapod](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/tetrapod) - Oxford Dictionaries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a direct answer to your question, a four-legged pod is more correctly called a **tetrapod** as there is little usage of *quadpod*. All that there is, are a few modern neologisms that can be found on [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22quadpod%22).
The more common words for a four-legged pods are formed in a similar way to the added 'r' in quadruple; **quadrapod**. Quadrapod has double the number of [Google Books hits](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22quadpod%22#tbm=bks&q=%22quadrapod%22) but, predictably, it's not that easy: as Sumelic says, and [Ngrams agrees](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=quadpod%2Cquadrapod%2Cquadripod%2Cquadrupod&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cquadrapod%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cquadripod%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cquadrupod%3B%2Cc0), the vowel used after the 'r' is a source of some controversy; *quadrapod*, *quadripod* and *quadrupod* are all about as common as each other.

However, even if you use *quadrapod*, *quadripod* and *quadrupod*, [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tetrapod%2Cquadpod%2Cquadrapod%2Cquadripod%2Cquadrupod&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctetrapod%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cquadrapod%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cquadripod%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cquadrupod%3B%2Cc0) shows a massive bias towards using **tetrapod**:

[image: Ngrams analysis]

Furthermore, there is a general linguistic convention that you try to use the same language when forming a new term. As such, you use the Greek prefix **tetra** to match the Greek word **pod** (limb/foot).

Comment: "Quadrapod" is weirdly formed. Not many Latin words are based on "quadra"; it's not really a productive prefix. The normal combining form is "quadri-" (most Latin combining forms end in the vowel "i") and the form used before labial consonants like "p" was "quadru-", as in "quadruped". According to the OED, there are some words formed in modern English with the prefix "quad-", such as "quadplex".

Comment: @sumelic Yes, I was surprised. Nevertheless, that seems to be the used word.

Comment: @sumelic Wait! [An Ngrams search for *quadripod* as well](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=quadpod%2C+quadrapod%2C+tetrapod%2C+quadripod&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cquadrapod%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctetrapod%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cquadripod%3B%2Cc0) puts *quadripod* and *quadrapod* about even.

Comment: What does this mean: *The more common word, in quadrapod, formed in a similar way to the added 'r' in quadruple, it has double the number of Google Books hits.*

Comment: Why not [quadruped](https://goo.gl/nFRWq1)

Comment: @Kreiri As highlighted [here](http://wikidiff.com/biped/bipod) there is a difference between -pods and -peds

Answer (score 5):

Since *pod* is Greek for *foot*, it takes (by convention) a Greek prefix. Unfortunately, *bipod* is an exception to this rule, since *bi-* is a Latin prefix (it should really be dipod).

So, to answer your question, it should be *tetrapod*.

[The Phrontistery: Numerical Prefixes](http://phrontistery.info/numbers.html)